# Forced Slowdown of Multiprocessing Generation vs OSError Too Many Open Files

Tags: python, multiprocessing, oserror

I have the following code.  In testing, I found that when I get several hundred concurrent child processes (somewhere around 400?), I get "OSError Too Many Open Files".  Any idea why?

I can solve the problem with the time.sleep(.005) call, but I shouldn't have to.

This is a part of a larger program.  A typical call will set a server string, token string, and a list of many thousands of devices.  For the REST API call used, the server can only handle a single device at a time.  In testing, this resulted in a 20 min execution time, but indications are that using a multiprocessing approach can reduce it to around 30 sec.

```
import urllib, requests, json, sys, pprint, time, multiprocessing as mp

assert sys.version_info >= (3, 6), "Must use Python 3.6+"

###########################
### handler function for multiprocessing worker
###########################

def getAttributesOneDevice(server, device, token, q):
    """Handler function for getting a single device"""
    serverURL = server + "/ServicesAPI/API/V1/CMDB/Devices/Attributes"
    headers = { "Accept" : "application/json",
                "Content-Type" : "application/json",
                "token" : token }
    query = { "hostname" : device }

    response = requests.get(serverURL, headers = headers, params = query, verify = False)
    q.put(response.json())
# end getAttributesOneDevice()

def GetDeviceAttributes(server = "", token = "", devices = []):
    """
    See this URL for explanation of what this function does
    https://github.com/NetBrainAPI/NetBrain-REST-API-V8.02/blob/master
                      /REST APIs Documentation/Devices Management
                      /Get Device Attributes API.md

    To summarize the URL: will acquire detailed device attributes for a single
    device.

    This subroutine therefore queries for all devices provided, and assemble the
    results into a single list of dicts.

    Server queries are relatively expensive.  A single query is not a big deal,
    but accumulated across a massive device list and this can take excessive
    time to execute (20min, etc). Therefor, this procedure is parallelized
    through multi-processing to complete in a reasonable amount of time.

    'server' should be a string that is just the http(s)://<FQDN>.  Do not
    incude the trailing '/'.

    'token' should be an authentication token that was generated by
    GetLoginToken and SetWorkingDomain modules in this directory.

    'devices' should be a list of strings, where each entry is a device.

    return a single dictionary:
        "Table" a list of dicts, each dict the detailed attributes of a device
        "Missed" a list of devices that had no result

    Note that failure to capture a device is distinct from function failure.
    """

    resultsTable = []
    MissedDevices = []
    procList = []

    for dev in devices:
        q = mp.Queue()
        proc = mp.Process(target=getAttributesOneDevice,
                          args=(server, dev, token, q))
        proc.start()
        procList += [ {"proc" : proc, "dev" : dev, "queue" : q} ]

        # If I don't do this as I'm going, I *always* get "OSError too many open files" 
        updatedProcList = []
        for proc in procList:
            if proc["proc"].is_alive():
                updatedProcList += [proc]
            else:
                # kill zombies
                if proc["queue"].empty():
                    MissedDevices += [ proc["dev"] ]
                else:
                    queueData = proc["queue"].get()
                    resultsTable += [ queueData ]

                while not proc["queue"].empty():
                    # drain whatever's left before we closeout the process
                    proc["queue"].get()
                proc["proc"].join()

        procList = updatedProcList

        # if I don't do this, I get "OSError too many open files" at somewhere
        # around 375-400 child processes
        time.sleep(.005)

    # I could instead embed the list comprehension in the while statement,
    # but that would hinder troubleshooting
    remainingProcs = [ 1 ]
    while len(remainingProcs) > 0:
        remainingProcs = [ proc for proc in procList if proc["proc"].is_alive()]
        time.sleep(1)

    for proc in procList:
        # kill zombies
        if proc["queue"].empty():
            MissedDevices += [ proc["dev"] ]
        else:
            queueData = proc["queue"].get()
            resultsTable += [ queueData ]

        while not proc["queue"].empty():
            # drain whatever's left before we closeout the process
            proc["queue"].get()
        proc["proc"].join()

    return { "Table" : resultsTable, "Missed" : MissedDevices }
```

Comment: Creating 400 child processes is utterly pointless.  Unless you have a mondo server, you have 8 or 12 or 16 processors.  Creating 400 processes means they are all thrashing, competing for scarce resources.  You should create a pool that allows, say 25 or 50 to run at a time.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by a "mondo" server, but it's incredibly beefy.  Something like 128 processors and 1 TB of RAM.  (It's a management platform for 30,000 network devices - a lot of work on the server to just manage the network.)  I did some network profiling, I figured out the slow per-query response is due in large part to long network one-way delay.  I wish I could send request for more than one device at a time, but the remote server is a vendor's product and I can't control that.  Ergo, I'm not taking up server resources, but rather overcoming network bottleneck.

Comment: I agree with @TimRoberts but would add the suggestion that ProcessPoolExecutor might be an even better approach. When constructed with no explicit parameters that class will optimise the maximum number of concurrent processes by introspection of your hardware (CPU) capabilities. Not only is that likely to improve overall performance but also reduce to complexity of your code

Comment: What exactly is the question? Do you want to know which files are open? Or do you want to increase the limit?

Comment: I'm trying to (a) understand why I need to limit process generation rate and (b) understand what I need do to engineer-away the problem.  I'm intrigued by the ProcessPoolExecuter (I also found ThreadPoolExecuter).  Short answer is I need to convert to pools rather than trying to manage all that by hand, whether with manual pools like @BooBoo says or with Pool Executer like suggested here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using multithreading with a multithreading pool (which can easily handle up to 500 threads) based on seeing that `getAttributesOneDevice`  spends almost all of its time waiting for a network request to complete. You should also use a `requests.Session` object for doing the GET requests because according to the documentation:

> The Session object allows you to persist certain parameters across requests. It also persists cookies across all requests made from the Session instance, and will use urllib3’s connection pooling. So if you’re making several requests to the same host, the underlying TCP connection will be reused, which can result in a significant performance increase (see HTTP persistent connection).

**The worker function, `getAttributesOneDevice`, should be modified to raise an exception if it fails to capture a device.**

```py
import urllib, requests, json, sys, pprint, time
from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool
from functools import partial

assert sys.version_info >= (3, 6), "Must use Python 3.6+"

###########################
### handler function for multiprocessing worker
###########################

def getAttributesOneDevice(session, serverURL, token, device):
    """Handler function for getting a single device"""
    query = { "hostname" : device }

    response = session.get(serverURL, params = query, verify = False)
    # Raise an exception if unable to capture a device
    response.raise_for_status()
    # Should the response itself be checked to ensure a device was captured
    # and an expection be raised if not?
    return response.json()

def GetDeviceAttributes(server = "", token = "", devices = []):
    """
    See this URL for explanation of what this function does
    https://github.com/NetBrainAPI/NetBrain-REST-API-V8.02/blob/master
                      /REST APIs Documentation/Devices Management
                      /Get Device Attributes API.md

    To summarize the URL: will acquire detailed device attributes for a single
    device.

    This subroutine therefore queries for all devices provided, and assemble the
    results into a single list of dicts.

    Server queries are relatively expensive.  A single query is not a big deal,
    but accumulated across a massive device list and this can take excessive
    time to execute (20min, etc). Therefor, this procedure is parallelized
    through multi-processing to complete in a reasonable amount of time.

    'server' should be a string that is just the http(s)://<FQDN>.  Do not
    incude the trailing '/'.

    'token' should be an authentication token that was generated by
    GetLoginToken and SetWorkingDomain modules in this directory.

    'devices' should be a list of strings, where each entry is a device.

    return a single dictionary:
        "Table" a list of dicts, each dict the detailed attributes of a device
        "Missed" a list of devices that had no result

    Note that failure to capture a device is distinct from function failure.
    """

    with requests.Session() as session, \
    ThreadPool(min(len(devices), 500)) as pool:
        session.headers = { "Accept" : "application/json",
                            "Content-Type" : "application/json",
                            "token" : token }
        # Compute this once here:
        serverURL = server + "/ServicesAPI/API/V1/CMDB/Devices/Attributes"
        # The serverUrl and token arguments never vary:
        worker = partial(getAttributesOneDevicesession, serverURL, token)
        resultsTable = []
        MissedDevices = []
        results = pool.imap(worker, devices)
        device_index = 0
        while True:
            try:
                result.append(results.__next__())
            except StopIteration:
                break
            except:
                # This is the device that caused the exception.
                # The assumption is that devices is indexable:
                MissedDevices.append(devices[device_index])
            finally:
                device_index += 1
```

Comment: Are *requests* Sessions thread-safe?

Comment: I know there is a bit of chatter as to whether the Sessions object is thread safe or not. My belief is that as long as you are going to the same website repeatedly you should not have a problem (I have never encountered one) and if cookie data plays no part in what you are doing, I would think that even going against multiple websites shouldn't be an issue. Also, [this page](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/v2.9.1/) lists "Thread-safe" as a feature of the package with *no qualifications* and looking at the code revealed no issues to me.

Comment: is it better to use mutithreading or multiprocessing?  I read https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/difference-between-multiprocessing-and-multithreading/ and went with multiprocessing because it has independent memory space and uses multiple processors, and I wasn't overly concerned about the memory/performance hits.  Should I re-evaluate?  It's been >20years since I was in a CompSci program so my memory is stale on the point.

Comment: Multithreading uses far fewer resources, you can create hundreds of threads, it allows you to share a Session object and as long as your worker function is mostly waiting for I/O or a network request to complete, it should perform well. If you do have some CPU-intensive processing, you can additionally create a multiprocessing pool whose size is the number of CPU cores you have that you pass to your multithreading pool worker function. Then after that worker does a GET, it can call `pool.submit` passing data to the multiprocessing pool for processing.

Comment: I had an internal conversation on the topic.  My team is Network Engineers; I'm the only one with a CompSci degree, and even then all my programming experience was as a student/theoretician rather than a software engineer.  The vendor's REST documentation uses requests rather than sessions, so I'm forced to uses requests in order to ease supportability.  Also, given the thread-safe concern (not even just for sessions but in general), it's far less expensive to buy a working computer to execute the code with 10x more hardware resources than are needed, than to support code that breaks because

Comment: my team is (and will likely remain) "relatively" inexperienced.    Ultimately this means I need to go down the multiprocessing route, by organizational needs rather than what is technologically optimal.  however, I hear the feedback on using pools rather than hand-managing things.  Once I test it, I'll mark this as answered.

Comment: Well, since your tasks do seem to be in a wait state most of the time, you should certainly have a multiprocessing pool size greater than the number of CPU cores that you have. But I can't tell you how many would be too many as it would be a function of your resources.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you @Booboo and @Olvin-Roght for your help.  I've marked Booboo's answer and the "accepted" answer, ultimately it was a combination of the two.  Here's what I actually ended up with, for transparency and in case it helps anyone else in the future, but I only got here with the pointers from the folks on this thread.  Thank you to everyone.

```
import requests, json, sys, concurrent.futures

# tested on 3.6.8
assert sys.version_info >= (3, 6), "Must use Python 3.6+"

#needed to REALLY condense the letters in the function name for submit()
def get1Dev(server, device, token):
    """Handler function for getting a single device. raises an exception if
    unseccessful query, or returns the dict of the detailed attributes table."""

    serverURL = server + "/ServicesAPI/API/V1/CMDB/Devices/Attributes"
    query = { "hostname" : device }
    headers = {
        "Accept" : "application/json",
        "Content-Type" : "application/json",
        "token" : token
    }

    # ProcessPoolExecutor already handles all exceptions
    response = requests.get(serverURL,headers=headers,params=query,verify=False)
    if response.status_code is not 200:
        raise Exception(str(response.status_code) + " returned from server")

    responseStatusDescription = response.json()["statusDescription"]
    if "Success." not in responseStatusDescription:
        raise Exception(f"{responseStatusDescription} returned from server")

    return response.json()["attributes"]
# end get1Dev()

def GetDeviceAttributes(server = "", token = "", devices = []):
    """
    See this URL for explanation of what this function does
    https://github.com/NetBrainAPI/NetBrain-REST-API-V8.02/blob/master
                      /REST APIs Documentation/Devices Management
                      /Get Device Attributes API.md

    To summarize the URL: will acquire detailed device attributes for a single

    This subroutine therefore queries for all devices provided, and assemble the
    results into a single list of dicts.

    Server queries are relatively expensive.  A single query is not a big deal,
    but accumulated across a massive device list and this can take excessive
    time to execute (20min, etc). Therefor, this procedure is parallelized
    through multi-processing to complete in a reasonable amount of time.

    'server' should be a string that is just the http(s)://<FQDN>.  Do not
    incude the trailing '/'.

    'token' should be an authentication token that was generated by
    GetLoginToken and SetWorkingDomain modules in this directory.

    'devices' should be a list of strings, where each entry is a device.

    return a single dictionary:
        "Table" a list of dicts, each dict the detailed attributes of a device
        "Missed" a list of devices that had no result

    Note that failure to capture a device is distinct from function failure.
    """

    # will raise() if needed; purposefully not including in a "try" block
    inputValidate(server, token, devices)

    # remove all empty strings in 'devices'
    devices = [ dev for dev in devices if dev ]

    resultsTable = []
    MissedDevices = []

    # profiling data for max_workers, 06 Feb 2022:
    # single-threaded single-processed: 20min (ish)
    # 61 is default, took 6min
    # 10000 resulted in "too many open files" error
    # detailed analysis: "too many open files" occurs ~350-400 child procs
    # 300 took 40sec, so we'll call that the "sweet spot"
    exe = concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=300)

    # exe.map() is too trivial in that it halts on first exception :(
    # derived from example for ThreadPoolExecutor
    # https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html
    results = {exe.submit(get1Dev, server, dev, token): dev for dev in devices}
    for result in concurrent.futures.as_completed(results, timeout=300):
        try:
            # separating calling result() from the += allows exception handling
            # without worrying about adding error result to resultsTable
            res = result.result()
            resultsTable += [ res ]

        # need to catch both exceptions
        except (Exception, concurrent.futures.TimeoutError):
            # not sure why, results[result] is related dev in devices, as desired
            MissedDevices += [ results[result] ]

    return { "Table" : resultsTable, "Missed" : MissedDevices }
```